# Диапазон типа float

Tags: c, память, типы-данных, float

Читаю Ритчи и Кернигана. Си. Говорится, что float представляет собой 32-разрядный тип, но потом написано, что его диапазон 10<sup>-38</sup> – 10<sup>+38</sup>. Почему именно так, если 2<sup>32</sup> - это вовсе не такое огромное число с 38 нулями. Чем обусловлен такой широкий диапазон при такой разрядности?

*И, будьте добры, подскажие литературу, которая поможет расставить точки над i относительно таких понятий, как "слово", объяснит, как устроена в машине память, как разрядность влияет на работу и т.д. У меня на примете только Танненбаум, Архитектура компьютера. Или это не сойдет?*

Comment: [Число одинарной точности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)

Comment: Ещё подробнее [тут](http://ru.exploringcomputerarithmetic.org/articles/fp/IEEE-754/basics/). На самом деле диапазон больше за счёт денормализованных чисел. Начинается он от `1e-45`, а не от `1e-38`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Тебе нужно смотреть описание стандарта  числа с плавающей запятой IEEE 754.

только к целочисленным типам таким как byte применимы обычные преобразования двоичной системы счисления в другие, в числах с плавающей точкой всё несколько сложнее и каждый разряд числа несёт свой функционал, а разрядность по сути определяет размерность и точность

более подробно [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)

Answer (score 5):

"Диапазоном значений" арифметического типа называется разность между максимальным и минимальным представимым в данном типе арифметическим значением. Эта разность никак не связана с количеством битов в представлении данного типа, а обуславливается лишь договоренностями о том, каким образом *интерпретируются* комбинации значащих битов, т.е. по каким правилам они отображаются на собственно арифметические значения.

В качестве экстремального примера можно привести воображаемый экзотический тип, состоящий всего из одного бита. Договорившись, что нулевое значение этого бита кодирует значение `0`, а единичное значение этого бита кодирует значение `1000000` мы получим тип с диапазоном значений в один миллион. При этом данный тип будет состоять всего из одного бита. Каким образом так получилось? Очень просто: мы просто пропустили все промежуточные значения между `0` и `1000000` - они в нашем воображаемом типе вообще не представимы.

Совершенно аналогичная ситуация имеет место с плавающими типами, представленными в формате IEEE754, включая наш `float`. Эти типы допускают представление лишь некоторых частных арифметических значений, отстоящих друг от друга на определенное расстояние. И чем дальше мы удаляемся от нуля, тем больше становятся промежутки между представимыми значениями. Вот такими все увеличивающимися и увеличивающимися прыжками тип `float` в конечном итоге и допрыгал до значений ±10<sup>38</sup> на обоих концах диапазона.

При этом количество различных представимых значений в этом типе, разумеется, никак не может превысить 2<sup>32</sup>

Comment: `±10^38` знак к степени надо бы отнести.

Comment: @alexolut: Зачем к степени? Со знаком, отнесенным к самому числу диапазон получается еще более впечатляющим.

Comment: Просто у ТС в вопросе указаны именно min/max значения для положительных значений.

Comment: @alexolut: Ну если ТС удивлен диапазоном 10^-38...10^+38, то диапазоном -10^+38...10^+38 он будет удивлен еще больше. Суть-то вопроса не меняется. Или вы считаете, что вопрос был о чем-то другом?

Answer (score 2):

Грубо - из-за округлений. Пусть тот же `int` совершенно одинаково представляет числа в пределах сотни - т.е. для него что 123456, что 123448 - одно число. Тогда вы получите, что диапазон чисел, представимых этим `int`, вырастает в 100 раз.

Если вы к `float` 10<sup>30</sup> прибавите единицу - он этого не заметит... 
Вот вам простенькая программка - что реально нужно прибавить к этому 10<sup>30</sup>, чтоб `float` это заметил - убедитесь сами:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    float x = 1e30f;
    for(int i = 0; i < 30; ++i)
    {
        double delta = 1.0;
        for(int j = 0; j<i; ++j) delta *= 10.0;
        if (x != x+delta)
        {
            printf("delta = %f\n",delta);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```